# How to write javascript equivalent of Convert.ToBase64String() in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have byte array and I can convert this usin Convert.ToBase64String() method in c#.
I wrote equivalent of this method in javascript like below. But the result is different.

in c#:

```
 byte[] data = ...
Convert.ToBase64String(data)
```

in js

```
    function GetStringFromByteArray(array) {
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                result += String.fromCharCode(array[i][j]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How can I succeed this in js?

Comment: Not duplicate. The question is about byte array, not string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the result is different, because the Javascript function doesn't do base64 encoding at all.

The base64 encoded data contains six bits of information per character, so the eight bits of a character code is spread out over two characters in the encoded data.

To encode the data, you have to regroup the bits in the bytes into six bit groups, then you can convert each group into a base64 character.

See: [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this javascript library](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html)